# How to keep a tab on the elements visited in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list

```
lis = ["Cat","Dog","Tiger","Elephant","Donkey","Fox"]
```

Say I reassign certain elements

```
lis[0] = "Lion"
lis[3] = "Zebra"
```

such that now my list is

```
lis = ["Lion","Dog","Tiger","Zebra","Donkey","Fox"]
```

Now I have to return the elements that are unchanged.How do loop through the elements and ignore the ones that have been changed and return the unchanged elements?My idea is to keep some sort of a check such that as soon as it hits the check condition,it ignores the element and moves on.

Note-I need to do this without deleting any elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep a data structure around that contains the indices of the modified elements. Then, while looping, you then check if the index of the item is in that structure.

Ideally, you'd use a `set` (for fast membership testing) and `enumerate` (for traversing a container while also getting its indices):

```
changed = {0, 3}  # after you modify the list
for index, elem in enumerate(list):
    if index not in changed:
        # do something with element that wasn't changed.
```

Comment: So I maintain a seperate set.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

@JimFasarakisHilliard has given you a potential back end to this problem (+1), allow me to tack on a potential front end to form a complete solution:

```
def track(index):
    changed.add(index)
    return index

changed = set()

my_list = ["Cat", "Dog", "Tiger", "Elephant", "Donkey", "Fox"]

my_list[track(0)] = "Lion"
my_list[track(3)] = "Zebra"

for index, element in enumerate(my_list):
    if index not in changed:
        print(element) # do something with element that wasn't changed.
```

Comment: Wow you added a new perspective to the solution!